# 'When a user is authenticated' in Flask

Tags: python, flask, global-variables, global, flask-login

Currently, I am using the following code in my prototype:

```
@app.before_first_request
def init():
 global project
 project = user_project.Project()
 project.init()
```

However, I have now programmed a user login using flask_login. Therefore, I need to change this function to trigger ONCE the user has logged in not just when the site is first requested.

I attempted the @login_required however, this does not explicitly launch this function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue, and both Django and Flask use a concept called "signals".

Have the user login function emit a signal, and have the init function listen (`connect()` in this case) to the signal.

Follow this guide:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/signals/

```
from flask import Flask, current_app, request
from blinker import Namespace

custom_signals = Namespace()
user_logged_in_signal = custom_signals.signal('logged-in')


def init(app, user, **extra):
 global project
 project = user_project.Project()
 project.init()

user_logged_in_signal.connect(init, app)

# example login
def login():
    # user logs in
    user = login(username, password)
    user_logged_in_signal.send(current_app._get_current_object(), user=user)
    return Response()
```

This one is more to the point: http://code.runnable.com/UqFCHJklakUbAAJT/creating-and-sending-signal-in-flask-for-python

```
@user_logged_in_signal.connect_via(app)
def init(sender, user, **extra):
   global project
   project = user_project.Project()
   project.init()
```

and no

```
user_logged_in_signal.connect(init, app)
```

Also seems viable and easier to read

Comment: This is a helpful start. I do have a few questions:  First, I am slightly confused as to what wrapper I would put over the init function above to connect() or listen for the signal. Would it be @connect or how does this portion of the process work?

Comment: you don't. `user_logged_in_signal.connect(init, app)` makes it listen for the signal

Comment: It seems from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/signals/ that you can put this decorator right above `init`: `@ user_logged_in_signal.connect_via(app)`. example now above

Comment: I am trying this but receiving the following error:     TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: I would trace back to what it's calling, look up how to use the function, and add the necessary argument